# Is there a command line tool like `gdalinfo` for vector files?

Tags: python, gdal, vector

I use `gdalinfo` all the time to obtain basic information about raster files. I was wondering if there was a similar tool to obtain information from vector files, such as the spatial projection, list of attributes and units, the types of geometries, etc? I can of course put a vector file into QGIS or use `geopandas`, but was just wondering if some command line tool already exists that is the equivalent of `gdalinfo.` I suppose I would prefer something in python if available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ogrinfo is what you need.

See:  https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs